Google Play publishing: "You're offline" - Integrity protection prevent app from working in offline mode
I published new version of my Android app and selected:
"Latest and strongest protection (version: enigma)"
And seems this is the reason that users can't launch my app when they in offline mode anymore. They get "You're offline" message. But I want my app is working during offline mode. What I should do in this case: publish new version without Integrity protection or are there some other solutions?

Did you find any solutions for this bug?

@MehmetPeker No, I just turned off Integrity protection and published new version.
